# How to Create an iOS HTTPS Login with Self-Signed Certificate using AFNetworking?

Tags: ssl, ios7, authentication, https, afnetworking-2

I would like to ask on How do you create an iOS HTTPS Login that handles Self-signed Certificate using AFNetworking 2.0? I looking across the web and searching here in stackoverflow but I couldn't start it. What I have is my Company's UserName and Password, and my Company's Self-signed Certificate. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. Make Credentials fields for your request
2. Turn off checking of valid certificates (!!! It's not for production
       !!!)

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:email password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
manager.credential = credential;    
//TODO: !!! not for production
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; // not for production
```